# Representation of Xml array with Openapi 3 and openapi generator maven plugin

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I try to generate Java DTOs from a YAML schema based on Openapi 3.0.3 specifications.

I use the Maven plugin : `org.openapitools:openapi-generator-maven-plugin:6.6.0`.

These POJOs are intended to be used by a REST client that consumes a web service returning an XML response that will be consumed by JAXB.

As the response of the service contains some lists of elements like this :

```
<Response>
<Statements count="5">
    <Statement label="" id="1">
    <Statement label="" id="2">
    ...
<Statements>
</Response>
```

My representation with OpenApi YAML format looks like :

```
Response:
  type: object
  xml:
    name: 'Response'
  properties:
    Statements:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/Statements'


Statements:
  type: array
  items:
    $ref: '#/components/schemas/Statement'
  xml:
    name: 'Statements'
    wrapped: true
  properties:
    count:
      type: integer
      xml:
        attribute: true


Statement:
  type: object
  xml:
    name: 'Statement'
  properties:
    label:
      type: string
      xml:
        attribute: true
    SubAttribute:
      $ref: ...
```

The generated Java class looks like :

```
public class Response {

  @XmlElement(name = "statements")
  @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Statements")
  private List<Statement> statements;
  
  ...
}
```

It's not the correct result and it leads to an error when this object is used for deserialization by JAXB when the generated API invokes the REST service : the 'response' object contains a list with 0 elements.
The problem is on `@XmlElement(name = "statements")`  that should rather be `@XmlElement(name = "Statement")`.

The annotation `@XmlElementWrapper(name = "Statements")` that defines the wrapper element is correct.

Did I miss anything in my YAML definition ? Or is there anything to fix in the openapi-generator Maven plugin ?